# Give a haml link an id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following code, but how do i set it so that the link has an id tag of *"title_header"* 
like this

```
<a href="/movies?sort=title" id="title_header">Movie Title</a>
%th{:class => @title_header}= link_to 'Movie Title', :sort => "title"
```

I tried this but it didnt work

```
%th{:class => @title_header}= link_to 'Movie Title', :sort => "title", :id => "title_header"
```

It gives me this

```
<a href="/movies?id=title_header&amp;sort=title">Movie Title</a>
```

Comment: That's not a "HAML link", that's a Rails method. `link_to` is not HAML. And nowhere to you tell `link_to_` what the URL of your link is supposed to be. How is it supposed to guess you want to link to "/movies"?

Comment: Well it creates a link to /movies?sort=title, its already in /movies. how can i create a link containing an id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use hash (#) to set Id?

```
%th{:class => @title_header}
%a#title_header{:href => "/movies?sort=title"} Movie Title
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close with your second example:

```
  %th{:class => @title_header}= link_to 'Movie Title', :sort => "title",
      :id => "title_header"
```

Should be:

```
  %th{:class => @title_header}= link_to "Movie Title",
      movies_path({:sort => 'title'}), {:id => 'title_header'}
```

Don't use a literal when specifying URLs (as shown in the answer you accepted); you're simply creating work for yourself when the app changes later.